# Images in pop-ups on webmaps ArcGIS online

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-online, popup, embeddable-web-maps, google-drive

[image]I am relatively new to webmaps - I am trying to add an image to pop-ups on web maps in ArcGIS and I am having problems getting the image to appear - all I can see is a little image icon with a tear through it as if it is having issues loading.

I have configured the pop-up media as they have listed in the instructions (http://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/create-maps/configure-pop-ups.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_B16A9E11A48D48CBAFA9DB964FCEB805) and have replicated the images to a smaller size (thumbnails) around 200x150 pixels so they shouldn't be too big to load. I have also tried loading the URLs from Google drive.

The links actually work if you click on it and request to open the image in a new window - but i want the image to appear in the pop-up as well and it just wont appear - does anyone have any advice or solutions for this?

I read on a troubleshooting link that it may be because the url is a https rather than a http, would this be it?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE, Can you show a screen shot of what you are seeing?

Comment: As a follow-up comment is the image hosted somewhere (i.e., AGOL, Flickr, Facebook, Web Server, ect...) and be publicly accessible

Comment: @whyzar, I do not think a snapshot would help that much but I would like to see a limited version of the webmap, say with a couple of features extracted from the main layer with deducted attributes, if necessary to **inspect** what the real problem is...

Comment: An example of your image link would help I think I remember having trouble with the google drive links and I had to use an older format.

Comment: Hey @whyzar so this is the link for the map - http://arcg.is/2eVgAO8...... and this is one of the photo urls - https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2DezzTccGmxSl9ONThEbDdsWWs
the images were originally jpg files and then i tried converting the images to png and that doesnt work either...

Comment: @whyzar i originally had the photos on dropbox and had a shared link with them available to be viewed publicly but then read that you cant have pop-up images from dropbox so changed it to google drive with a shared link for public viewing..

Comment: @CatAAI I believe the issue is in the links that you are using currently. You mention that you want the image to be displayed in the pop-up window when the point is clicked. What you mind have a hyperlink instead that take you to your image?

Comment: @whyzar preference is to have the images appear in the pop-up rather than a hyperlink - any suggestions as to how i can fix this??

Comment: @CatAAI I believe we are getting close to finding a fix for your issue. Can you provide a screen shot of the configure image pop-up that you used to setup the url. As that might be where the issue lies in conjunction with were you currently store your images. I would have an answer for you once I have to check that out, if you can.

Comment: @whyzar i have just attached a screenshot of the configure pop-up to my original question. let me know if you need anything else! thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3):

The past few days I've had a chance to look further into what potential issues [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/141497/how-to-get-images-displayed-on-arcgis-online-popups?rq=1), [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/162335/show-attached-images-inside-popup-with-arcgis-online) and [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/120431/how-to-add-link-in-arcgis-online-web-map-popup-to-google-or-bing-driving-directi) may be causing your image to not display as a thumbnail in the configure pop-up in line portion of the dialogue box.

Furthermore, looked at some potential solution [here](https://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2012/07/03/add-flickr-photos-to-arcgis-online-web-maps/), [here](https://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2012/04/26/tips-for-displaying-photos-in-pop-ups/#comment-3801) and [here](http://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/create-maps/configure-pop-ups.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_0505720B006E43C5B14837A353FFF9EC). The solution range from external links from image storage sites as well as specifics to how the configure pop-up is either to be a hyperlink or a thumbnail.

To get to the solution, I believe the issue lies in the URL that you have been using to display the image in-line within the configure pop-up box. [Here](https://geonet.esri.com/thread/92769) is a good example of choosing the image directly through the URL with an extension .png and .jpeg. So you could try to copy the image address directly of the image and that might work within the URL.

An alternative option would be to create a field in your shapefile in ArcGIS Online [image]

then use an image storage site like [imgur](http://imgur.com/), create an account, upload the image [image]

and use the direct link to insert in the ArcGIS Online [image],

this approach worked for me
[image].

Comment: You were right the issue was with the links i was using! The URLs i was using linked to the website where the image was embedded rather than linking to the actual image itself. I opened up the image in google drive and right clicked on it and selected "copy image address". This gave me the URL to the image itself which i added in to the table which has allowed the image to appear in the pop-up. Thanks heaps for your help!

Comment: Just a reminder if the question has been ansewred, you can indicate that.

Answer (score 2):

With help from Whyzar i managed to find a solution to this issue. 
i was trying to make an image appear in the pop-up based on a URL to thumbnails of images unique to each feature in a layer. I had the images stored in a folder on google drive and the URL was taken from clicking on the image and selecting "get shareable link" - however this URL would take you to the website where the image was embedded rather than to the image itself, so the pop-up would only show that there was a broken link to the picture rather than the picture itself. The solution is to load the image into a separate window and then right clicking on the image and selecting "Copy image location/address". This gives you the URL to the image itself.

Thanks everyone for your help!

Comment: CatAAI Thanks a lot for you answer. This was easiest and fast solution for view the picture in the pop up with out duplicate the picture.